# Qtimer does not call function every 5 seconds

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qt-creator

I created a form using Qt creator.The form has three tabs and each tab has 30 fields.So I want the data  on the form to be refreshed every 5 seconds.I sed `QTimer` class to achieve this functionality. Here is my code:

MainWindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <QPixmap>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <QProcess>
#include <QString>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QPen>
#include <QBrush>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QTimer>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

void load_Tab1Values(Ui::MainWindow* ui)
{
    // append values
}

void load_Tab2Values(Ui::MainWindow* ui)
{
    //append values
}

void MainWindow::onTabChanged(int tabIndex)
{
    cout<<"the tab index is:"<<tabIndex<<endl;
    if (tabIndex == 0)
    {
        // Create the first tab elements

        cout<<"tab 0"<<endl;
    }
    else if (tabIndex == 1)
    {
        // ...

        cout<<"tab 1"<<endl;
    }
}

void MainWindow::refresh_values()
{
    cout<<"values refreshed"<<endl;
}

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    time_t now = time(0);
    char* dt = ctime(&now);

    ui->setupUi(this);
    this->setWindowTitle("First Qt Project");

    load_Tab1Values(ui);
    load_Tab2Values(ui);
    connect( ui->tabWidget, SIGNAL(currentChanged(int)), this, SLOT(onTabChanged(int)) ); 

    QTimer *timer= new QTimer(this);
    timer->connect(timer,SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(refresh_values()));
    timer->start(5000);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

MainWindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui
{
    class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void ontabchanged(int tabIndex);    

    void refresh_values();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

According to the code the function refresh_values should be called every 5 seconds but the function is not called. Should this be added in Main.cpp for it to be called every 5 seconds.Could you let me know what I am missing here. Thanks.

Comment: Try `qDebug() << connect(timer,SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(refresh_values()));` and include QDebug. What did you get, true or false?

Comment: @Chernobyl So I added these statements cout<<"start"<<endl; qDebug() << connect(timer,SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(refresh_values())); cout <<"end"<<endl; when I do that I got the output as start end true. The function is still not being called repeatedly.

Comment: @Chernobyl no change..the function is still not called. As I have three tabs on the form whenever i click on the tabs this function is called.I am not sure why this is called when the tab is clicked. Even then the function should be called every 5 secs when the Qtimer is used right.Also is is that the timer should be in the main.cpp instead of mainwindow.cpp?

Comment: Something strange, it is not your full code, right? Post full code and QTimer works on mainWindow.cpp . You shouldn't do this in main.cpp

Comment: @Chernobyl I have edited both the files and it is the code I have. I have added the onTabChanged slot in the header file and in the mainwindow.cpp I am calling two functions before the QTimer which loads the values into the fields in the tab.Is that causing a problem?

Comment: @Chernobyl I found the solution,I declared it in the public slots section in the header file(Mainwindow.h) and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for this issue:

by default any slots which are created are under the section of "private slots" in the MainWindow.h file as shown below:

```
private slots:
//default slots created from the ui(when the user right clicks on a button and then connects to a     slot)
```

So in my case since the function refresh_values is a user defined function and I manually created a SLOT for this function this should be in public slots section. So including it this way resolved the issue.

```
public slots:

    void refresh_values();
```

Comment: I believe that's just C++ standard for class kicking in.  Anything not under public or protected will be private... not just slots.

Comment: @kiss-o-matic Yes It is a c++ standard. I was referring to slots in this case just to propose a solution to the issue that I was getting while adding slots. When the slots are created manually the user might define them in the private slots section which is already available.